# How to survive The Last Stand Classic in Dawn of War II

Tags: warhammer-40k-dawn-of-war-ii

How to survive all 20 waves of The Last Stand in Dawn of War II + Chaos Rising?

As far as I played this game, there is almost no problem to achieve 16th wave. In 16th wave, one could have some problems or complete it in about 1-2 minutes. But after this wave we have the 17th, 18th and 19th waves with some bosses and the ultimate 20th wave with epic bosses, re-spawned previous bosses and separated players. Personally I have no idea how to beat this level. Do you have some working strategy for achieving this?

Answer (score 5):

Mobility is the key. Hit and run, use your abiities smart and whatever you do, don't waste energy. That said, don't be so overly cautious with energy that you never use it, but don't spam rok strikes on single guys or summon dreadnoughts when you already have one. You should already know the effectiveness of blitzing one entrance at the start before everything merges into one massive crapstorm in the middle. A great stratergy is to kite your enemies around the outsides of the board, turning every once in a while to fire of shots etc. 
Wave 20 is terribly difficult and it's annoying to fail after you've gotton so far. Once it starts, try to link up with your teammates as soon as possible, negotiate an entrance beforehand and try move to it around the outside of the board, as fast as you can. A farseer's group teleport can certainly help to move teamates rapidly around the board. 
I do recommend a suppression weapon in wave 20. And all the minions you can muster. Forms of confuse can make a great impact as well. Finally, superabilities; Orbital Strikes, Roks, and Eldritch Storms can truly turn the tide of all the battles from wave 17 onwards, they are espacially deadly when coupled with suppression or knockdown weapons. Remember however, whatever you put on your hero will be thrown back in your face at wave 16.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with wave 20 is: you not only have to deal with the super boss that spawned, but you also have to deal with your doppelgangers from wave 16 again, and they can revive every enemy heroes that died from wave 17 to 19. And in case it wasn't hard enough, the game also throws 24 Bloodletters at you.

Depending on your team composition, it might be harder or practically impossible to win too. For example, the space marine captain has a trinket called something of the tireless crusader, which allows him to instantly revive an ally player for 35 energy. Pretty handy, right? The doppelgangers also find it very handy. Especially since they have 1.5 times your health and energy, allowing them to withstand more damage and using it more often. Not only that, they also have 2 times your damage output.

You have to find a team composition that actually makes the doppelgangers weak/easy to kill, while also making you strong enough to survive that far.

On wave 20, the key here is to kill the 3 doppelgangers as fast as possible, because they are the only ones with the ability to revive other heroes. If you kill any other hero before them, and there's still at least 1 doppelganger alive, they might revive the others, including the super boss. However, if you kill the 3 doppelgangers, none of them will revive anymore and you can already consider the game as won, as long as you take out the remaining enemies one by one.

Best case scenario, you need to be able to kill (some of) them within the first 15 seconds. After that, they might start reviving the other heroes and the Bloodletters start spawning, and that's going to be harder.

If initial attempt at finishing it fast failed, the game turns into a gauntlet. You need to find a way to split the enemies to take them out one by one, while also making sure to stick together to help each others, and running away to avoid being attacked by the bulk of the enemies, because nothing can tank 7 heroes and 24 Bloodletters indefinitely.

The best way to survive here is to avoid the middle of the map at all cost, because you are exposing yourself to being attacked from every sides, and the same goes for anyone who might attempt to revive you if you died there. It's best to run in circle around the map, behind the towers. My personal favourite pattern is to run in a counter clockwise pattern. Clockwise works too, but I feel more at ease doing the opposite.

Jumping into a gate (jump pack, ork tellyporta, sorcerer warp staff) might also make the enemies temporarily forget about you, which gives you a second or two of respite to regenerate health and energy; unless a farseer has mass teleport, which means enemy farseer could teleport all the enemies into you without you knowing.

While you are running away, some enemies might catch up to you faster than some others. When it happens, you should combine strength with your team mates to take them out, and then start running again when it looks like the bulk of them are catching up to you.

It's best to start killing the Bloodletters one by one, and then start picking on the heroes afterwards, starting with the doppelgangers when one of them is isolated from the others (the one with the lowest health and armour rating).

That was the "basic". Now, for a few tips:

- Mobility is key here, so if you can, it can help to have an ability to teleport/jump away. Avoid slow weapons because you might be stuck in an attack animation and won't be able to run away. It's best to pick something which is both fast and strong.
- Use cover to reduce ranged damages, and flank enemies when they are in cover. And if you are in danger, remember that enemies cannot attack something they cannot see: if you hide behind a wall, a pillar or a building, they have to walk around it to actually see and shoot you.
- The farseer has an ability that can be used to temporarily confuse an enemy, making them attacking each other. It's a pretty neat ability, because enemy farseer cannot use it against the players, but you can use it against them. However, enemy farseer can still use it against players' pets (aka. space marine's dreadnought, hive tyrant's tyranids, and sorcerer's doppelganger). It's a good idea to use it against the weakest hero on wave 20, then watch them getting destroyed by the other hard hitting ones.
- Sometimes, hero doppelgangers will forget about chasing you to focus on reviving a fallen enemy hero. Usually, that's a bad thing and you would use any knocking ability to interrupt it (assuming the character isn't unshakable). But while they're in the process of reviving, they will also be vulnerable to attacks, making them an easy target.
  What I usually do is I kill the Lictor in a safe spot (somewhere secluded). Since it's the fastest, it catches up to me before the others (so it's isolated from the others). It's also among the weakest heroes, so it's not too hard to kill it before the entire bulk catches up to you. After I'm done killing it, I keep running until only one doppelganger attempts to revive it while alone. Then the entire team needs to kill the doppelganger, then rinse and repeat. However, if the Lictor is being revived while its corpse is circled with enemies, don't attempt an attack. Just wait for the next opportunity and try again.

When everything goes perfectly as planned, wave 20 can be done in less than a minute. But if things go horribly wrong and you get stuck in a gauntlet, it could go on forever.